# Does this updated $\frac{0}{0}$ two-dimensional limit exist?

Tags: differential-geometry, limits, multivariable-calculus

This is a question closely related to the [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/114658/9464) I posted two days ago.

Thanks to Christian Blatter's answer to that question, the limit (there are 9 limits here indeed.)
$$
\lim_{y\to\xi}\frac{(\xi_i-y_i)(\xi_j-y_j)({{\xi}-y})\cdot n(y)}{|\xi-y|^5},\quad 1\leq i,j\leq 3,\tag{1}
$$
does not exist *in general*. Here $S\subset{\mathbb R}^3$ is a surface which has a continuously varying normal vector, $\xi=(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3)\in S$, $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)\in S$, $n(y)$ is the unit normal vector at point $y$. Here $(\xi-y)\cdot n(y)$ is the dot product.

The key point in the counterexample is that the quotient is of order $\frac{1}{|\xi-y|}$. I am interested in the following "updated" limit:
$$
\lim_{y\to\xi}\,[\psi_j(\xi)-\psi_j(y)]\frac{(\xi_i-y_i)(\xi_j-y_j)({{\xi}-y})\cdot n(y)}{|\xi-y|^5},\quad 1\leq i\leq 3,\tag{2}
$$
where the Einstein summation convention is applied for $j$ here and $\psi_j:S\to{\mathbb R}$ is assumed to be $C^{\infty}$. Or without normalization, consider the limit
$$
\lim_{y\to\xi}\,[\psi_j(\xi)-\psi_j(y)]\frac{(\xi_i-y_i)(\xi_j-y_j)({{\xi}-y})\cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial\alpha}\times\frac{\partial y}{\partial\beta}}{|\xi-y|^5},\quad 1\leq i\leq 3,\tag{3}
$$
where $y(\alpha,\beta)=(y_i(\alpha,\beta))_{1\leq i\leq3}$ is a parameterization of $S$.

Here is my **question**:

> Does the updated limit (2) or (3) exist in general?

Intuitively, the $[\psi_j(\xi)-\psi_j(y)]$ term may compensate the order of the numerator. But I don't have an idea for the general case even for unit ball.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Robert's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90135/does-this-frac00-2-dimensional-limit-exist/90486#90486) on MO, the limit generally do not exit.

The key point is that one should use a "special" parameterization of the surface in order to simplify the quotient.